# I am having error: cannot find symbol but i think that my variables are all declared and initialized

Tags: java

it is supposed to be a word guesser game, giving 5 chances to enter a consonant before guessing the word it is still not complete but i have to know if this part of the program runs well. i think the variables that are giving me trouble are consonants, vowel, number  Here is my code: ps im very new to java

```
public class julia1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     System.out.print("enter text to guess: ");
     String w = Keyboard.readString();

     String asterix = "";

     for(int c = 0; c < w.length(); c++){
        if(w.charAt(c)==(' ')) asterix = asterix + " ";
        else asterix = asterix + "*";
        }
     System.out.println(asterix);


     for (int trys = 0; trys <=5; trys++){ 
        String temp=""; 
        System.out.print("enter a consonant: ");
        char c1 = Keyboard.readChar();
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++)
    {
        boolean character  = false, vowel = false, consonant =false,                   number= false;
        if (w.charAt(i) >= 'a' &&w.charAt(i)<='z')
        character = true;

        if (w.charAt(i) >= 'A' && w.charAt(i)<='Z')
        character = true;

        if (character == true){
            switch (w.charAt(i)){
                case 'a': case 'A': case 'o': case 'O':
                case 'e': case 'E':
                case 'i': case 'I':
                case 'u': case 'U': vowel = true; break;

        if (c1 >= '0' && c1 <='9')
            number=true;        
                default : consonant = true;

            }
        }
    }
      for(int c = 0; c < w.length(); c++){ 
          if((w.charAt(c)==c1) && (consonant == true ))
             temp = temp + c1;
             else if (vowel==true) 
                  {temp = temp + asterix.charAt(c);
                  System.out.println("this is a vowel not consonant");
                  }
                 else
                  temp = temp + asterix.charAt(c)&& number==true; 
                  System.out.println("this is not a valid letter");}

       asterix = temp; 
       System.out.println(asterix) ;
} 



  }
 }
```

Comment: At which line are you getting that error? Post the compiler error here.

Comment: Which line is the error?

Comment: if((w.charAt(c)==c1) && (consonant == true ))
                         ^
  symbol:   variable consonant
  location: class julia1
E:\julia1\src\julia1.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
   else if (vowel==true) 
            ^
  symbol:   variable vowel
  location: class julia1
E:\julia1\src\julia1.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
        temp = temp + asterix.charAt(c)&& number==true; 
                                          ^
  symbol:   variable number
  location: class julia1
3 errors

Comment: @JuliaCaruana Please edit your question. It is nearly impossible to read code in comments.

Comment: Edit the error into the main body of the question, after the code.

Comment: One suggestion. Please format your code properly. Many such compiler errors are easily solved with the help of proper formatting.

Comment: The line `boolean character  = false, vowel = false, consonant =false, number= false;` needs to move outside the for loop at line 21. This will resolve some of the issues, but there is another issue with `temp = temp + asterix.charAt(c)&& number==true;` in that this invalid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you have declared `consonant` inside one for loop and then try to use it inside another. This is not allowed as the scope of `consonant` ends at the end of the for loop where you declare it.

Answer (score 6):

You have declared variables `boolean character = false, vowel = false, consonant = false, number = false;` inside `for` loop, and tried to use them outside this loop, but inside other `for` loop. This is the cause of your compile error.

Comment: @JuliaCaruana, don't try 'something else'. Just place this code-line-string `boolean character = false, vowel = false, consonant = false, number = false;` **before** line `for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {`

Comment: P.S. unfortunately this is not the last mistake in your code, but this will solve this first problem...

Answer (score 4):

These variables:

```
boolean character = false, vowel = false, consonant = false, number = false;
```

are declared within a for loop which implies that their scope is restricted to that for loop. When you try to reuse them in the next for loop, they don't exist any more.

Either you want to be able to know what their final value was at the end of the previous loop, in which case you need to increase their scope by declaring before the first for loop. Or you don't and you can simply redeclare them within the second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
 boolean character  = false, vowel = false, consonant =false,
```

You are end with , but it should be ;

2) Define your character  , vowel , consonant out side the for loop otherwise it will scope to that for loop only.

If you define them as class variables you don't need to initialize to false and its default value is false.

```
public class julia1 {

 boolean character, vowel , consonant ;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
```

3)      `temp = temp + asterix.charAt(c)&& number==true;` line is invalid